# Create Accessible writer within multiple Packages

Tags: java, maven, access-modifiers

I'm trying to create a `File Writer` which can be utilized in different packages under one maven project.

In my scenario, whole maven project is converted into a jar and I use that jar in my other Java application.

And I start using that jar, by calling one of the method of below class in Jar.

```
public class Transmission{

   static void startDoingSomethin(String Txn, String fileName){

      //doing something   
  }

}
```

The file `fileName` gets created into Java application from where am using Jar and calls the method. I'm passing filename as parameter in `startDoingSomething` method.

Is there any way I could create any kind of static or instance variable (`Writer`), so that I could use it anywhere I want within the Jar ?

Lets say my Variable's would be like this

```
Writer traceFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName), true)));
```

Any suggestions please, how and where should I place this Writer `traceFileWriter` in class `Transmission` or any other place, so that I could call it everywhere in jar and use it to write in a file.

Thanks

Comment: You can bundle Java packages into a jar. Then you can use the jar in other projects. If you build the jar with Maven, you can reference it as a Maven dependency in other projects. I do not understand your static function and your intentions behind it.

Comment: @JFMeier, I'm looking for one file Writer whose file location I'll be giving and then use that writer every where in Jar ..! How can I do it ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create your own Writer class. If you want, you can add static variables and a static function and use that class throughout your project.